# How to get Amazon product information through API

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am looking for a way how to get Amazon product information through API. I found some articles how to get products data:

[Amazon Product API Exploration: Let’s Build a Product Searcher](https://www.sitepoint.com/amazon-product-api-exploration-lets-build-a-product-search/)

[Querying Amazon's product details with the Amazon Product Advertising API](https://grantwinney.com/querying-amazon-product-details-with-the-amazon-product-advertising-api/)

If I understand it correctly, I need access to **Amazon Product Advertising API**. I signed up as Amazon associate, but I wasn't approved, and thus I am not able to join Amazon Product Advertising API.

**I messaged Amazon support and got this response:**

---

This is the Amazon Associates team responding to your email.

Registration for Product Advertising API is only available to Associates who have received final acceptance into the Associates Program and are in an Open status. You are unable to join because your application is still pending or in a Pending status. PA-API is only for approved members or those in an Open status. This means that when the Applications team review your application and website(s), if your application is placed into an Open status, you will be automatically eligible for API access.

Our Applications team will review your application and website(s) after you have earned at least three (3) qualifying referral sales through your Associate Product Links. Please note, three (3) qualifying referrals means three separate orders and multiple items within an order do not qualify. Applications will be reviewed shortly after you’ve referred your third qualifying sale to Amazon.com.

To begin developing your website(s) and posting on social media, you've been granted access to Associate Product Linking tools in Associates Central (affiliate.program.amazon.com) under the Product Linking tab and Site Stripe (located at Amazon.com). Use these tools to generate at least three (3) qualified referral sales to initiate your final review. Until your application is reviewed. With the access to Associates Central, you have the opportunity to create product links, banners, or native ads to add to your website and start earning money right away.

If your website requires the use of PA-API, you would need to contact them directly to see what other options would be available, or use our other Product Linking tools on a different website or social media site(s).

---

I am wondering, **how can I get access to amazon product information if I am not amazon seller**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon recently changed their affiliate policy regarding API access. They want you to have three affiliate link transactions within 180 days to be in good standing. They will need to conduct a review of your affiliate site. Until then, the API keys will only be good for generating product links.